# How to remove space (margin/padding) of ion-row and ion-col in ionic?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework

Here is my code:

```
<ion-content padding text-center>
    <img src="../assets/img/logo.png" width="200" class="logo" />


</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
    <ion-row no-padding>
        <ion-col col-6 align-self-stretch>
            <button ion-button full>Button</button>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-6 align-self-stretch>
            <button ion-button full>Button</button>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

I need to remove those paddings/margin for ion-row and ion-col. I tried googling but i got no luck. I am also newbie in Ionic. TIA!

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I need to achieve this:

[image]

Comment: add `no-padding-class` to the `buttons`

Comment: If you're debugging Ionic with chrome you can just use the inspector to find the divs + classes created by ion-col and ion-row. (see here)[http://mcgivery.com/debugging-ionic-apps-chrome-developer-tools/]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to set the `no-padding` attribute on ion-col instead of ion-row and `no-margin` for the buttons.

```
<ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6 no-padding>
        <button ion-button full no-margin>Button</button>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6 no-padding>
        <button ion-button full no-margin>Button</button>
    </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Answer (score 16):

For those using Ionic4+ , use `class="ion-no-padding"` or `class="ion-no-margin"`.

```
...
<ion-col class="ion-no-padding">
   <ion-button class="ion-no-margin">Button</ion-button>
</ion-col>
...
```

For more info please refer to the docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/layout/css-utilities#element-padding.