# How to remove unwanted whitespace between mat-card-header and ion-grid

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, angular-material

I am working on an Ionic angular application.

On the page I'm currently working on I have an angular material `<mat-card>` with a `<mat-card-header>` (red border) with two `<mat-card-title>` tags each inside an `<ion-col>` (blue border) and formatted with `<ion-grid>` (pink border). To organize my overall formatting for the card I'm starting by attempting to remove any padding that exists by default. To get rid of this padding I have a `no-space` class in my CSS with the following properties.

```
.no-space {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

This class is applied to the following tags `<mat-card> <mat-card-header> <ion-grid>`. There is still space between the `<ion-grid>` and the `<mat-card-header>`. What could be causing the spacing to still exist? Below I'll include a screenshot showing this space with the HTML and SCSS files

HTML file

```
<mat-card class="no-space">
  <mat-card-header class="red-border no-space">
    <ion-grid class="pink-border no-space">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col class="blue-border">
          <!-- formatted to left showing starting date -->
          <mat-card-title>Example Date</mat-card-title>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col class="blue-border"></ion-col>
        <ion-col class="blue-border">
          <!-- formatted to right side shows money spent / total -->
          <mat-card-title>$$$/$$$</mat-card-title>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
  </mat-card-header>
  <!-- a progress bar displaying spent / total -->
  <mat-card-content class="no-space">Simple Card</mat-card-content>
  <mat-card-actions class="no-space">
    <ion-button fill="solid" color="tertiary">Expand Card</ion-button>
  </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

SCSS file

```
.red-border {
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.pink-border {
  border-color: pink;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.blue-border {
  border-color: blue;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-style: solid;
}

.no-space {
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

[image]

EDIT: I've tried this solution but it didn't remove the whitespace [How to remove space (margin/padding) of ion-row and ion-col in ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671659/how-to-remove-space-margin-padding-of-ion-row-and-ion-col-in-ionic) See my comment below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove space (margin/padding) of ion-row and ion-col in ionic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47671659/how-to-remove-space-margin-padding-of-ion-row-and-ion-col-in-ionic)

Comment: No that link was one of the solutions I tried before posting the question. I'll add an edit to show I've already tried this. To double-check I tried adding the `ion-no-padding` and `ion-no-margin` to each tag from the `<mat-card-header>` to the `<ion-col>` and the space is still present. A bandaid solution I found was adding -30px of margin-left to the ion-grid but I'm wondering what is causing the space in the first place.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the space and inspecting the dom element for the CSS?

Comment: Thanks for this recommendation, I was able to find a solution see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from E. Maggini I found what was causing the extra space. An extra `<div>` with the class "mat-card-header-text" is added into my code when it compiles. See picture below.

[image]

The best solution I found to fix this is to add styling to the .mat-card-header-text class to reduce the margin to 0 [See solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43479557/how-do-you-deal-with-div-with-mat-card-header-text-in-an-material2-card). To properly apply the styling include the ::ng-deep combinator before the class. The use of ::ng-deep has been deprecated but there [dosen't seem to be a good replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024236/what-to-use-in-place-of-ng-deep) so since this is a side project I'll still use it. I found [one recomendation](https://www.reddit.com/r/Angular2/comments/uxge19/ngdeep_alternatives/) to precede ::ng-deep with :host to prevent unwanted behavior from using ::ng-deep. Here is the final code I used for my solution.

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-card-header-text {
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```